# Using Redux with models

Tags: reactjs, models, redux

I've started using Redux with React and I absolutely love it. However, the problem I'm having currently is that besides state, I also have more information I need to store/use throughout my application.

In this specific case I have a model with state that's fetched from an API. This model also has some info about itself, e.g. how you display a property on the screen "name" => "Name of the blabla". I understand how to work with state using Redux, but I'm have trouble seeing what do with this other info that I still need propagated throughout the application but is not actually state.

Comment: At first glance, that seems like state to me.  What objection do you have to putting `name` in state?

Comment: The name itself is indeed state, however the "label" of that name property is not state. It's information about the properties in the model.

Comment: If the "label" of the name is used as props in a component, I would say that it is state.

Comment: So how would you structure all that information?

Comment: Both as properties of the entity.  So, if the label is dynamic of a person:  `{ name: 'Robin', label: 'name' }`, then I'd expect that to be reduced into a person record.

Comment: Did you read the redux docs? It has a centralised store to put anything you want in. The guide also shows that it's typical you might keep some UI state data in there.

Comment: Yes I read the redux docs tons of times. But I'm having a hard time putting it all together in my mind. Especially when I want to combine models that get data from an API and also have model information with Redux that simply has state.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Redux, the State is the only "source of truth". And it should not have duplication (which would lead to inconsistencies).

So your state should store the `name`, but not the *computed* label property.

Indeed, "Name of the blabla" is a function (in the mathematical sense) of your Name value, and if they differ (for example, if at some point name === 'foo' but the label is 'Name of the bar' instead of 'Name of the foo'), then you have a problem...

So what I would do, is just store the minimum in your state (name in that case), and compute the label directly in the Component, where you need it.

If you need that to be re-used, then create a Component that only does take your name as a prop, and render a string with "Name of the blablaba" (if name = blabla I suppose).

If you need more complex computation (say you have multiple labels, date calculations etc.), you can always create a function that takes your State in input, and spit out your "Model" in output with everything calculated.

Redux is very functional in nature, so you might as well embrace it :)

Comment: I believe I prefer this approach.

Comment: Why can we not let the state subtree itself be an immutable model ?

Answer (score 9):

I know I'm kind of late to the party but I thought someone might use the answer. What has work for me this far after working with React for some years now is to have a structure that is sort of like this:

- State: which sets the structure (or 'schemas') of my data.
- Actions: make changes to this state. These actions can handle sync or async operations.
- Sagas: they handle async actions.
- Selectors: they handle the structure of the data that I need for the view/for the API.
- Constants: other data that won't change through time and that makes no sense to add to my state.

So having said that the flow of my apps is something like this:
An `ACTION` is dispatched => If that action is async a `SAGA` is listening and it performs the fetch operation => This saga saves updates to the `STATE` => [React components layer from now on] => If my view needs the data from my state in a different format for whatever reason I send it through a `SELECTOR` which will change that format => Then I attach this new parsed data to my container component.

An other flow could be one in which you need static data that is not in your `state`. In that cause I would save it in an object in a separate file and would import it to my container component directly (I never import anything in my children/presentational components directly. Only other components. The data is handled in a separate layer than the components).

A third kind of flow I can think of right now is when you need to make a POST to your API and for whatever reason the data in your state needs some parsing before doing so. In that case I would do the same that in the first example but the other way around: dispatch an `ACTION` => that is handled by a `SAGA` => before doing the fetch I would bring my data already structured for my POST (sagas has a method called `select` to help you use selectors here) => then I would perform the async operation => update the state accordingly.

Just in case you don't know what I mean by selectors or sagas some links here:

- Sagas: https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga
- Selectors: https://github.com/reactjs/reselect

Answer (score 0):

I think models are as necessary for a Redux based app as for any other system.

Models are the vocabulary of a system. Models bring sanity to the codebase. Without them a codebase looks like a series of insane distorted thoughts.

You can use state functions to fill in the need of models in ReactJS+Redux apps.
**Just like models hold data and methods, these objects hold only the functions that can be applied to state.**

Read here : https://medium.com/@nshnt/state-functions-for-modeling-with-redux-a9b9d452a631.

Here is the famous Redux TODO app example with state functions :

**todo_reducer.js :**

```
import TODO from './todo_state';

const todoListReducer = (state=TODO.initialState(), action)=>{
  switch(action.type){

    case 'ADD_TODO' :
      return TODO.addTask(state, action.taskName);

    case 'FINISHED_TODO':
      return TODO.setFinished(state, action.taskID );

    case 'PENDING_TODO':
      return TODO.setPending(state, action.taskID );

    default :
      return state;
  }
};

export default todoListReducer;
```

**todo-state.js :**

```
export default {
  initialState: () => [],

  addTask: (todoList, name)=> todoList.concat({id: todoList.length, name: name}),

  setFinished: (todoList, taskId) => (
      todoList.map(task=> task.id === taskId ? {...task, complete: true} : task)
  ),

  setPending: (todoList, taskId) => (
      todoList.map(task=> task.id === taskId ? {...task, complete: false} : task)
  ),

  pending: todoList=> todoList.filter(task=> !task.complete)

};
```

I also use these state functions in component, if component need some manipulation of state.

**todo_list.js :**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import TODO from './todo_state';

const TodoList = ({tasks, showCompletedTasks, toggleTodo})=> {
  const toListElement = (task) => (
      <li key={task.id}>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={task.complete} onChange={(e)=> toggleTodo(task)}/>
        <label>{task.name} {task.complete ? "Complete" : "Pending"}</label>
      </li>
  );
  const visibleTaskList =
      (showCompletedTasks ? tasks
      : TODO.pending(tasks)).map(toListElement);

  return (
      <ul className="todo-list">
        {visibleTaskList}
      </ul>
  );
}
.....
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use Reselect

[Reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) is a simple library that sits in your app. It's primary function is to aggregate data from your redux store.

### Create a reselect function

Taken from https://medium.com/@parkerdan/react-reselect-and-redux-b34017f8194c

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'
// selector
const getBar = (state) => state.foo.bar
// reselect function
export const getBarState = createSelector(
  [ getBar ],
  (bar) => bar
)
```

The idea is that you connect your component with `redux-connect` or `map state to props` but instead of using the store directly you pass the store to a selector. This selector will have a function that lets you aggregate data or transform it any way you like.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getBarState } from '../selectors'
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    bar: getBarState(state)
  }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can reuse a selector on any component quite easily. You manipulate your data before it ever reaches a component ([Separation of concerns principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)). This gives you 2 big advantages.

- Firstly, your redux store can remain unpolluted with duplicate or calculated data.
- Secondly, your components can be built to expect data structures that immediately make sense to them.

### Conclusion

Reselect helps your React apps become more structured.